# Do something when a certain screen width and class are present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my body element to drop 12ems when the top menu opens up. I went through a few answers similar to mine but no luck. It doesn't break but it doesn't seem to run either. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
   var w = window.innerWidth;

    if ( w < 991.98 && $('#mainNav').hasClass('header-active') ) {
      console.log("hello")
       $('#target').addClass('body-active');
   } else {
       $("#target").removeClass("body-active");
   };

<!--body tag top and nav-->
   <body id="target">

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid hero">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <header class="masthead d-flex justify-content-center">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top" id="mainNav">
     Nav</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <i class="fas fa-bars fa-inverse"></i>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
       <div class="navbar-nav">
         <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
         <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
         <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
```

```
.header-active {
   background-color: $blk !important;
  }
.body-active {
   margin-top: 12em;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing more context for that code, it looks like it will just run once when the page loads and then never again.

Comment: You need to execute this code when the menu is opened - presumably there's an event triggered when this happens. Your current logic will only ever run when the page loads, presumably when the menu is closed.

Comment: You have to place this code whre you are triggering the menu to pop.

Comment: Where are you running that? needs to be inside a `resize` event listener

Comment: It would also help to see your HTML and CSS. Could you please edit it in to the question.

Comment: Added my html and css

Comment: why don't you use CSS Media Queries ?

Comment: @seifeddineBesbes it needs to trigger ONLY if the screen is a certain width AND if a certain class is present. I'm not aware of a way that CSS media queries can detect if a class is present but if you know what let me know.

Comment: If that code is just sitting in a `<script>` at the top of  the page, it won't do anything at all.

Comment: @GracieSullivan ok i have tried to test your code and it's working 
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/62570/
perhaps you have a problem with adding the header-active class to mainNav?
can you share the code responsable for adding this class ?